# Array.find vs Array.forEach in performance

Tags: javascript

I was wondering if anyone knows if Array.find will short circuit the loop when the first item is found.  I couldn't find anything googling.

Has anyone done any performance comparisons between find and forEach?

Comment: I think it almost certainly does escape the loop

Comment: The docs for `find` *explicitly* state it returns as soon as the first match is found.

Comment: Yes, it does, as [the MDN page clearly states](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find#Description)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is not a benchmarking, not programming question

Comment: ah. not sure how i missed it.  it does say immediately return.  so it think it's safe to assume it will be more performant than forEach

Comment: ok for closing it. how do i close it?

Comment: @techguy2000 you should mark one of the two answers as having solved your question

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> The find() method returns the value of the first element in the provided array that satisfies the provided testing function.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find

`Array.find` will return the first result that matches the callback condition.

Performance wise they're both O(n), albeit `find` is likely to cycle through less loops, therefore would be more performent in that respect.

Comment: A more relevant quote is the first paragraph of the **Description** section.

Comment: Why is `find` likely to cycle through fewer loops?

Comment: Once it finds the result, it breaks the loop and returns it. forEach will continue cycling through the entire length.

Answer (score 3):

> I was wondering if anyone knows if Array.find will short circuit the loop when the first item is found.

Yes, it will. This is clear from the [spec](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-array.prototype.find), which shows it bailing as soon as the callback has returned a truthy value. Step 6(d):

> If `testResult` is true, return `kValue`.

(Separately, it would be odd to keep searching even though a result had been found. If there had been early spec language doing that, it would have been caught and corrected before being finalized, and/or challenged by the makers of JavaScript engines [and others] as being inefficient.)

Answer (score 1):

As you can see the polyfill code in [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find#Polyfill), you can notice that `find` loops until if there is something matched item.

Here is the part of that;

```
// 6. Repeat, while k < len
      while (k < len) {
        // a. Let Pk be ! ToString(k).
        // b. Let kValue be ? Get(O, Pk).
        // c. Let testResult be ToBoolean(? Call(predicate, T, « kValue, k, O »)).
        // d. If testResult is true, return kValue.
        var kValue = o[k];
        if (predicate.call(thisArg, kValue, k, o)) {
          return kValue;
        }
        // e. Increase k by 1.
        k++;
      }
```

So,  `∀ n ∈ [0, len - 1]: n <= len - 1`

Comment: There's no such thing as "the source" of JavaScript. The only source of truth is the spec (and even that doesn't *guarantee* anything, whether or not it should).

Comment: Yes, You are right. It is `polyfill` code which is a piece of code (usually JavaScript on the Web) used to provide modern functionality on older browsers that do not natively support it.

Comment: @DaveNewton Here is the definition of polyfill. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Polyfill

Comment: ... I know what a polyfill is. I don't know why its definition is relevant, but thanks.